# onDataChange not called

Tags: android, firebase

I'm trying to read from Firebase (offline), but the method onDataChange is never called,

```
private class MyAuthStateListener implements Firebase.AuthStateListener {
    @Override
    public void onAuthStateChanged(AuthData authData) {
        if (authData != null) {
            // user is logged in
            userId = authData.getUid();
            mFirebase = mFirebase.child(authData.getUid()).child("xxx");

            Query mQuery = mFirebase.orderByChild("externalId").equalTo(externalId);

            mQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new MyValueEventListener());
        }
    }
}

private class MyValueEventListener implements ValueEventListener {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot mDataSnapshot) {
        if (mDataSnapshot.hasChildren()) {
            Iterable<DataSnapshot> i = mDataSnapshot.getChildren();
            Iterator<DataSnapshot> mIterator = i.iterator();
            if (mIterator.hasNext()) {
                mArrayList.clear();
            }
            while (mIterator.hasNext()) {
                DataSnapshot c = mIterator.next();
                mArrayList.add(c.getValue(mObject.class));
            }
        }
        onTaskComplete(); // call the notifyDataSetChange() on the adapter.
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
    }
}
```

Have I done something wrong?
Online it works well, but offline it won't works.
The new objects are created with a FAB that open a new activity (to modify the object) and than I return to that activity.
Thank you all for the help.

Comment: Add a `Log.e()` to `onCancelled()` to find out if your listener is being canceled.

Comment: Ok, I found out that the ValueEventListener is not cancelled and continue update. How can I remove it?

Comment: https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-detaching